# Variable declaration after goto Label

Tags: c, goto, variable-declaration

Today I found one interesting thing. I didn't know that one can't declare a variable after a goto label.

Compiling the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int x = 5;
    goto JUMP;
    printf("x is : %d\n",x);
JUMP:
    int a = 0;  <=== giving me all sorts of error..
    printf("%d",a);
}
```

gives errors like

```
temp.c: In function ‘main’:
temp.c:7: error: expected expression before ‘int’
temp.c:8: error: ‘a’ undeclared (first use in this function)
temp.c:8: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
temp.c:8: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

Now what is the logic behind that? I heard that **one cannot create variables inside the case statements of switch**. Since JUMP is inside the same scope (the scope of main function, in my case) of the goto statement, I believe that scope is not an issue here. But then, why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The syntax simply doesn't allow it.  §6.8.1 Labeled Statements:

```
labeled-statement:
    identifier : statement
    case constant-expression : statement
    default : statement
```

Note that there is no clause that allows for a "labeled declaration".  It's just not part of the language.

You can trivially work around this, of course, with an empty statement.

```
JUMP:;
int a = 0;
```

Answer (score 18):

You want a semi-colon after the label like this:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main() {
     int x = 5;
     goto JUMP;
     printf("x is : %d\n",x);
 JUMP: ;     /// semicolon for empty statement
     int a = 0; 
     printf("%d",a);
 }
```

Then your code compiles correctly for the C99 standard, with `gcc -Wall -std=c99 -c krishna.c` (I'm using GCC 4.6 on Debian/Sid/AMD64).

Answer (score 7):

Simple explanation, other than the spec says not, is that the compiler is exepecting the code after the goto to be something that compiles into an operation which it can then calculate the offset of, and is kicking because your variable declaration isn't a statement/block that it can compile into such an offset.

Comment: The standard (and gcc) allows a _compound statement_ after a label, i.e., `JUMP: { int a = 0; printf("%d", a); }`; do you consider that such a statement is compiled into an operation?

Answer (score 6):

My gcc version (4.4) is giving this compile error:

```
t.c:7: error: a label can only be part of a statement and a declaration is not a statement
```

. This error-message says it all.

Answer (score 6):

If you know why you can't create variables inside case statement of switch, basically its the same reason why you cant do this too. As a fix, you can try this,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int x = 5;
    goto JUMP;
    printf("x is : %d\n",x);
JUMP:
    {                                              //Note this
       int a = 0;  // <=== no more error..
       printf("%d",a);
    }                                             //Note this
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, first you should be consistent. It's either `LABEL` or `label`. Second, label is a part of the statement and the declaration doesn't answer the description enough.

You can replace `LABEL:` with `label: ;` and then it is likelier to compile.

**EDIT:** Now that you edited your code all over, it should be `JUMP:` replaced with `JUMP: ;` ;-)

Comment: sorry about that..Changed to JUMP so that there is no confusion..And please consider this as an easy test program which reproduce what I am asking here..Those printf statements mean nothing.

Comment: That's okay. `printf`s mean nothing, I pointed you to the problem (and solution) regardless of `printf`s.

Comment: You all are saying, 1) A label needs to be a part of a statement. And **in C a declaration is not a statement.** 2) The error is nothing related with scope (which is what I first thought), correct?

Comment: No, it's not about the scope.

Comment: Then the same situation in switch case is also is not about the scope. right?

Comment: Yes, most likely. There may be different problems with bypassing variable initialization due to the jump, but you should get a decent diagnostic for that. And if you do, just separate declaration and initialization.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int x = 5;
    goto JUMP;
    printf("x is : %d\n",x);
JUMP:
    printf("Do anything after label but dont declare 
    anything. even empty statement will also work 
    because label can only be part of a statement");
    int a = 0;  
    printf("%d",a);
}
```