# Does goto construct create new variable

Tags: c, goto

In the following piece of code

```
label:
int a;
goto label;
```

Does it create new variables or use same variable
Also what happens when we call function again and again using goto

Comment: Just for clarification, did you have any compiler error using this code?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384388/variable-declaration-after-goto-label-c) is why I asked..

Comment: Just for concept i am asking does this causes memory leak

Comment: As an aside, be aware it is generally considered poor programming practice to use gotos as they can make the code path difficult to follow.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this won't build since a label must be followed by a *statement*, and a declaration isn't a statement:

> #### 6.8.1 Labeled statements
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> 1    labeled-statement:
>         identifier : statement
>         case constant-expression : statement
>         default : statement
> ```

Secondly, this *shouldn't* create a new variable.  `goto` does not introduce a new scope, and therefore doesn't create a new instance of `a` each iteration. And even in situations where you *are* introducing a new scope, such as

```
for (;;) {int a; ... }
```

the space for `a` is (usually) only allocated once; even though *logically* you are dealing with a new instance of `a` for each loop iteration, *physically* you are (usually) recycling the same memory location.  Any compiler that physically created new space for `a` *without reclaiming the previous space* would be grievously broken IMO.

Just for giggles I wrote the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef __STDC_VERSION__
  #if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
    #define C99
  #endif
#endif

int main(void)
{
label:
  #ifdef C99
    ;
  #endif
  int a;
  printf("&a = %p\n", (void *) &a); 
  goto label;

  return 0; 
}
```

built it with `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror`, and I get the following output:

```
&a = 0xbf98ad8c
&a = 0xbf98ad8c
&a = 0xbf98ad8c
&a = 0xbf98ad8c
&a = 0xbf98ad8c
&a = 0xbf98ad8c
&a = 0xbf98ad8c
&a = 0xbf98ad8c
&a = 0xbf98ad8c
&a = 0xbf98ad8c
&a = 0xbf98ad8c
&a = 0xbf98ad8c
&a = 0xbf98ad8c
&a = 0xbf98ad8c
```

Answer (score 1):

No It will not declare that variable again and allocate any memory to it. It will use the same variable.

Moreover your program is wrong, a label cannot be in front of any declaration, it must be before a statement and declaration is not a statement. So to correct it put a semi colon after the label.

Comment: I think you meant after the label, ie `label: ;`.

Answer (score 1):

This question could as well have been "how and when does the compiler allocate a local variable?", because that is the issue here.

Lets say we have code like this:

```
{
  lots_of_code();

  int x;

  lots_of_code();

  x = 5 + something;

  lots_of_code_not_using_x();

  return x;
}
```

This code is in a local scope. In this case it looks like the inside of a function, but the same rules would apply to the inside of an if-statement, for loop etc. When encountering this code, the compiler will ask itself some questions:

- Do I need to allocate x at all or could I just optimize it away? No, in this case x cannot be optimized away without changing the meaning of the code.
- Where is the best place to allocate x? This is completely CPU-specific: x could be allocated on the stack or in a CPU register etc.
- When do I allocate x? The answer to this is always: "when it is used for the first time". In this case, x will certainly not be allocated before the line `x = 5 + something;` is executed. It isn't necessarily allocated even then, the compiler could as well re-order the instructions, choosing to execute `lots_of_code_not_using_x();` first, if that is more efficient and does not change the meaning of the code. In that case, x is allocated when the code reaches the return statement.

x is guaranteed by the standard to be valid all the way from the point of *entering the scope*, until the end of the scope. 9899:2011 6.2.4

> "5 An object whose identifier is declared with no linkage and without
>   the storage-class specifier static has automatic storage duration, as
>   do some compound literals..." /--/
>
> "6 For such an object that does not have a variable length array type,
>   **its lifetime extends from entry into the block with which it is associated until execution of that block ends in any way**. (Entering
>   an enclosed block or calling a function suspends, but does not end,
>   execution of the current block.) If the block is entered recursively,
>   a new instance of the object is created each time. The initial value
>   of the object is indeterminate. If an initialization is specified for
>   the object, it is performed each time the declaration or compound
>   literal is reached in the execution of the block; otherwise, the value
>   becomes indeterminate each time the declaration is reached."

So to answer the question: no, your goto spaghetti doesn't affect how the variable is allocated in the slightest. Had there been any code using the variable, for example `int a = 0;` then that code would possibly have been executed over and over again, depending on how smart the compiler is to optimize away the whole goto mess.