# Switch-case won't compile after commenting out an unused line

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main (void) {

  struct addrinfo hints; 
  memset (&hints, 0, sizeof hints);

  hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; 
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;  
  hints.ai_flags = AI_CANONNAME;   

  struct addrinfo *res;

  getaddrinfo ("example.com", "http", &hints, &res);
  printf ("Host: %s\n", "example.com");

  void *ptr;

  while (res != NULL) {
    printf("AI Family for current addrinfo: %i\n", res->ai_family);
    switch (res->ai_family) {
      case AF_INET:
        ptr = (struct sockaddr_in *) res->ai_addr;
        struct sockaddr_in *sockAddrIn = (struct sockaddr_in *) res->ai_addr;
        break;
    }
    res = res->ai_next;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

which compiles fine.

However when I comment out this line:

```
//ptr = (struct sockaddr_in *) res->ai_addr;
```

I will get:

```
$ gcc ex4.c
ex4.c:30:9: error: expected expression
        struct sockaddr_in *sockAddrIn = (struct sockaddr_in *) res->ai_addr;
        ^
1 error generated.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe the title of this question should be edited? Can someone more experienced do this if agrees so?

Comment: You should be able to edit it yourself if you want.  But I agree, the title could be better.

Comment: @KorayTugay, I took a run at it.

Comment: Having a variable declaration inside a `case` (without surrounding braces as suggested by the top answer) is a bad idea because then the variable's name will be visible in later `case`s but it will be uninitialized (unless you dropped down).

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Each case in a switch statement is, technically speaking, a label. For some [obscure and old reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8384505/2908724), you are not allowed to have a variable declaration as the first line after a label. By commenting out the assignment

```
ptr = (struct sockaddr_in *) res->ai_addr;
```

the line

```
struct sockaddr_in *sockAddrIn = (struct sockaddr_in *) res->ai_addr;
```

becomes the first line after the label `AF_INET:` which, like I said, is illegal in C.

The solution is to wrap all of your case statements in curly brackets like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main (void) {

  struct addrinfo hints; 
  memset (&hints, 0, sizeof hints);

  hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; 
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;  
  hints.ai_flags = AI_CANONNAME;   

  struct addrinfo *res;

  getaddrinfo ("example.com", "http", &hints, &res);
  printf ("Host: %s\n", "example.com");

  void *ptr;

  while (res != NULL) {
    printf("AI Family for current addrinfo: %i\n", res->ai_family);
    switch (res->ai_family) {
      case AF_INET:
      {
        ptr = (struct sockaddr_in *) res->ai_addr;
        struct sockaddr_in *sockAddrIn = (struct sockaddr_in *) res->ai_addr;
        break;
      }
    }
    res = res->ai_next;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Anyway, I think this is better coding practice.

Comment: Nice. Nitpicking "Each case ... is ... a labeled-statement". And that's the reason: statements can be labeled but not declarations.

Comment: @KorayTugay Sometimes compiler messages aren't informative as we want them to be.... sometimes they are **too** informative (cough cough C++ stl cough cough).

Comment: @BlueMoon You're right.  When you can [buy](http://www.bdsoft.com/tools/stlfilt.html) a tool to simplify C++ stl error messages, you know the information density is incredibly low!

Comment: Is this also the case in C++?

Comment: @immibis I am 95% sure the answer is "no" for c++14 (check this [scce](http://ideone.com/ueKzto) with Koray's code), but I don't know much more than that.

Comment: or just move declarations before switch block

Comment: @immibis: In C++ declarations are statements, which is why in C++ you can label declarations without any restrictions. In C declarations are not statements, which is why you can't label them. Here's an example that illustrates this difference between C and C++: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19830820/187690

Answer (score 15):

As a complement to the accepted answer, you can declare your variables before the case labels.

```
switch(a) {
    int b; //can't initialize variable here
    case 0:
    ...
}
```

Or just use an empty statement.